# Route inside marker radius Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need your help
I need to know if in some point my route (A->B) is inside my Marker(C) radius
Is there a way to get some true or false of this event?

The idea of this its make something like Uber Pool algorythm or something close to that

```
JS:
function initMap() {
var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
    pointC = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2029, -0.1403),
    myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointA,
        title: "point A",
        label: "A",
        map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointB,
        title: "point B",
        label: "B",
        map: map
    }),
        markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointC,
        title: "point C",
        label: "C",
        map: map
    });
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
map: map,
radius: 1000,    // 10 miles in metres
fillColor: '#AA0000'
 });

circle.bindTo('center', markerC, 'position');
// get route from A to B
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

 }

 function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    avoidTolls: true,
    avoidHighways: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
});
 }

 initMap();
```

HTML

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

[Here´s](http://jsfiddle.net/u9no8te4/426/) the fiddle
Tks a lot

Comment: related question: [How to calculate the distance from a known point to the closest point in a route using Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278427/how-to-calculate-the-distance-from-a-known-point-to-the-closest-point-in-a-route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process through all the points in the returned directions polyline, check if any of them are in the circle.

```
  // convert the directions response to polylines
  renderDirectionsPolylines(response);
  // check to see if any of the points from the route are in the circle
  for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < polylines[i].getPath().getLength(); j++) {
      if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(polylines[i].getPath().getAt(j), circle.getCenter()) < circle.getRadius()) {
        console.log("route intersects circle at:" + polylines[i].getPath().getAt(j).toUrlValue(6));
      }
    }
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/je2sd486/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
    pointC = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2029, -0.1403),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map,
      preserveViewport: true
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    }),
    markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointC,
      title: "point C",
      label: "C",
      map: map
    });
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 1000, // 10 miles in metres
    fillColor: '#AA0000'
  });
  circle.bindTo('center', markerC, 'position');
  // get route from A to B
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, circle);

}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, circle) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    avoidTolls: true,
    avoidHighways: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      renderDirectionsPolylines(response);
      console.log("polylines=" + polylines.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < polylines[i].getPath().getLength(); j++) {
          if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(polylines[i].getPath().getAt(j), circle.getCenter()) < circle.getRadius()) {
            console.log("route intersects circle at:" + polylines[i].getPath().getAt(j).toUrlValue(6));
            var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: circle.getMap(),
              position: polylines[i].getPath().getAt(j),
              icon: {
                url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
              }
            });
            circle.getMap().fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
            // document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "route intersects circle at:"+polylines[i].getPath().getAt(j).toUrlValue(6)+"<br>";
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
var polylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 4
};
var polylines = [];

function renderDirectionsPolylines(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
    polylines[i].setMap(null);
  }
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
      }
      polylines.push(stepPolyline);
      stepPolyline.setMap(map);
      // route click listeners, different one on each step
      google.maps.event.addListener(stepPolyline, 'click', function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent("you clicked on the route<br>" + evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
        infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
      })
    }
  }
}
initMap();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Damn! Thats just what we are trying to do, thnks a lot man! We´re gonna to study more of gmaps API